# Which javascript event is fired when remove person from people picker?

Tags: 2013, javascript, people-picker, events

I want to handle the javascript event whenever the person is removed from the PeoplePicker control in new form of custom list.

If any person is removed then corresponding department value should be blank. Please suggest how to do so?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? looking to do something similar... S

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js` is running `DeleteProcessedUser`, `OnControlValueChanged` and `OnControlResolvedUserChanged` when I try removing someone from the PeoplePicker control in my SP2013 dev environment.
There's quite a few other functions being called from the `clientpeoplepicker.js` file also, but these seem to be the most relevant.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can add onblur event on the hidden textarea feild and check if it is empty or valid and do your logic.

```
$("textarea[id$='_UserField_downlevelTextBox']").onblur(function(){ <do your stuff here> });
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the function that is called : EERemove();

This is the structure:

```
<SPAN text="Remove" onMenuClick="EERemove();" type="option" iconAltText></SPAN>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please try to elaborate this question a bit more? It is not really clear what this EERemove() is and what it does